# Deploy local web server to public in GCE

Tags: web-services, dns, webserver, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a local web server running:

```
https://localhost:5555
```

Everything things in my laptop.
And let's say that I have bought my own domain `abc.com`.

What would be the easiest way to deploy this to `abc.com` in Google cloud?

1. Set up a VM machine and running the same program inside the machine.
2. Get the external (public ip) and open the port `5555` in network setting.
3. Now it works perfect, if I go to my `$PUBLIC_IP:5555`

But I can't figure out how to map these to my DNS so that if people click `abc.com`, then it redirects to my `$PUBLIC_IP:5555`. Is there any easy way to do this without setting up nginx or separate web server to route traffic in Google cloud platform?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people click on abc.com, their browser will default to port 80 rather than 5555. Assuming that your web server won't run on port 80 (or you don't want it on port 80), you can use `iptables` to [translate port 80 to port 5555](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/) like so:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5555
```

That covers the port part of the problem. The other part of the problem is mapping the domain name abc.com to `$PUBLIC_IP`. To do this, you'll need to go to the service where you registered the domain name and add an `A` record which maps to `$PUBLIC_IP`. [Here is Google's guide for how to do this with various registrars.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns#mapping_your_domain_name_using_a_third-party_dns_provider)